# Trying to build the cube and getting below error

Tags: ssas

I am trying to build the cube and getting below error:

What should I do to resolve it?

> Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully. Errors in the
>   OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when
>   processing: Table: 'dbo.FACT1', Column: 'LoanAge', Value: '-93'. The
>   attribute is 'LoanAge'. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The record
>   was skipped because the attribute key was not found. Attribute:
>   LoanAge of Dimension: LoanAge from Database: Cube_Data, Cube: Bond
>   Analytics OLAP, Measure Group: FACT1, Partition: Fact Combined
>   SUBPRIME 20180401 HPI Median, Record: 185597. Errors in the OLAP
>   storage engine: The process operation ended because the number of
>   errors encountered during processing reached the defined limit of
>   allowable errors for the operation. Errors in the OLAP storage engine:
>   An error occurred while processing the 'Fact Combined SUBPRIME
>   20180401 HPI Median' partition of the 'FACT1' measure group for the
>   'Bond Analytics OLAP' cube from the cube_Data database. Server: The
>   current operation was cancelled because another operation in the
>   transaction failed. Internal error: The operation terminated
>   unsuccessfully. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred
>   while processing the 'Fact Combined ALTA_20180401 HPI Median'
>   partition of the 'FACT1' measure group for the 'Bond Analytics OLAP'
>   cube from the Cube_Data database.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: You have a fact row with an LoanAge of -93 and that age isn't in your dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greg actually replied in comment under your question.

Let me enlarge his explanation a bit.

Table `dbo.FACT1` has a row with column `LoanAge = -93`

It's record #185597 when cube is doing T-SQL query to grab partition `Fact Combined SUBPRIME 20180401 HPI Median` data.

However this value ( -93 ) is not present in `LoanAge` dimension `LoanAge` attribute.

To fix it you need to:

1. add this value into `LoanAge` dimension table
2. "Process Update" `LoanAge` dimension
3. Process `Fact Combined SUBPRIME 20180401 HPI Median` partition again.

And figure out why dimension has no -93 value.

You probably need to implement late-arrival dimension scenario is your facts are coming earlier than dimension values.

E.g. one unknown value is comming from facts, add it, mark with some default name (e.g. 'Unknown -93'). And update them later once dimension reference table has this code.

This is the common case, not exactly it's applied to such simple attribute like age (numeric value with no additional description).